# Switching Views gives me a SIGABRT Message

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, viewcontroller, sigabrt

I'm having a little predicament switching between views, here.

Alright, so, I have this view controller class in my iPhone project called "`BaseViewController`," which is the default, which has a button called "`GoToNextView`." I added another ViewController to the storyboard called "`NextViewController`," and then I created another custom view controller class called "`NextViewController`." Under the inspector window for `NextViewController` on the storyboard I changed its custom class to "`NextViewController`;" I'm assuming everything should be hooked up, now. When I click on the "`GoToNextView`" button, though, the application stops with a `SIGABRT` message.

Here's the code for my button click action in the BaseViewController class.

```
- (IBAction)Transition_Next:(id)sender 
{
        nextViewController = [[NextViewController alloc] 
                                initWithNibName:@"SecondView" 
                                bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
        [self.view addSubview:nextViewController.view]; 
}
```

What might I be doing wrong, here?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
- (IBAction)Transition_Next:(id)sender 
nextViewController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
[self presentModalViewController:nextViewController animated:YES];
}
```

Instead of your code and it should work! Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [self.navigationController pushViewController:nextViewController animated:NO]; or if you don't have a navigation controller, you may use 
[self presentModalViewController:nextViewController animated:NO]; instead of [self.view addSubview:nextViewController.view];

Comment: I made that change; unfortunately, I'm still getting a SIGABRT message when clicking on the button.

Comment: can you pleasse post the SIGBART message ?
as you wrote in your question, you have added NextViewController.xib in your storyboard, but in your code, you are initiating your Nib name with "SecondView". Please check your Nib name & class name carefully.

Comment: Ah, you're right. Changing the name fixed the SIGABRT problem, but now I have a new problem: the newly load view isn't showing anything; it's blank, even though I added a bunch of stuff to it in the storyboard. What might have happened?

Comment: IT'S NOT SUPPOSED TO BE.....if your view controller's class & nib names are correct, then it should show all the stuffs you added in your nib file. check your storyboard that whether you have directed the nib file to a right class or not (i mean your NextViewController.xib should have the NextViewController as it's custom class).

Comment: Everything appears to be in order in that regard, but it's still blank.

Comment: I'm pretty confused about the issue. :-S
Well, you can check whether the right view is loading or not in such another way: in your NextViewController class, you can print a log (such as: NSLog(@"NextViewController loaded");)
in -(void)viewDidLoad function. Then after navigate to this view have a look in console window. If it is not showing the printed line, then the right view is not loaded. otherwise there seems some other problem in your code.